# Set default value in R

Tags: r, function, default-value

I have a function that requires 5 inputs

```
stpr<-function(series,n,percent,range,lmin){
...
}
```

I do not write the code of the function because I think it's not important for this question. Actually my question concerns the dafault values of a function. In my case the input `n` can be often equal to `length(series)`. How can I set this as a default value?

Comment: @Mako212 thank you. But `function(series,n = length(n),percent,range,lmin)` or `function(series,n = length(series),percent,range,lmin)`?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, you're correct it should be `function(series,n = length(series),percent,range,lmin)`

Comment: A simple example `f1 <- function(x, n = nchar(x)){x+n}`. `f1(10) == 12`, `f1(100) == 103`